# Which key to choose first for my index on SQL

Tags: indexing, key

I want to create a index using 2 keys : customers & products, so I can do a Query like  :

where customer_id = "NAME" and products_id = "XXXXX"

We have about 300 customers and about 100.000 products;

What of the keys should be first ??Why ?? Does it impact a lot the performance of the DB ??

Answer (score 0):

-The "customer_id" will first.
-It uses shorting.
-No